# In computers in general, are number caclulations treated like string when comparing?

Tags: int, compare, calculator, string-comparison

If I have `int myInt1 = 02` and `int myInt2 = 2`, in general, are they compared like strings so `myInt1 == myInt2` returns `false`, or does the computer compare it as you would if you're doing math on paper and return `true`?

Answer (score 0):

This would completely depend on the computer language under discussion, and (in the specific case of prefix 0's, as shown here) on the specific value of `n` -- at least as far as whether `n` and `0n` are the same.

That said, for the vast majority of programming languages, numbers are treated quite differently from strings, and if there are several ways of expressing the concept of the integer "two", they're generally all equivalent. That's not to say that `2` and `2.0` are the same: in many languages they're quite different.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the syntax and semantics of the language is defined.

You haven't specified which language you are talking about, but in most modern languages the **numeric value** is used for comparison. So you would normally expect to get `true` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, it entirely depends on the context and the language.  It also depends on the data type (`int, float, double`, some languages have others like `Decimal`, `NSNumber`, etc).

In `Objective-C`, if you compare two `NSNumber`s with `==`, it will typically return false, as `NSNumber` is an object, and in this case, comparing with `==` compares the memory address, so it's going to typically return `false`.

But in terms of `int`?  In most cases, even if you have a line of code that says `int myNum = 002;`, the language probably doesn't care about leading zeros.  Leading zeros could simply be a matter of formatting output.  For example, `printf("%03d",myNum)` versus `printf("%d",myNum)`.

Comment: Well, be careful there. Leading zeroes indicate octal integers in C-like languages. 02 is 2, but 010 is 8!